# Jetty Continuations/AJAX Push: Timeout best-practices?

Tags: java, ajax, jetty

I am using Jetty Continuations for a collaboration application.
I was wondering if there are any reasons for a smaller continuation timeout? Doesn't it make sense to have a very high timeout set?
The examples I have seen so far are between 5 secs-30 secs. Is there anything to keep in mind when I go higher (e.g. 2-5 minutes)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should remember that while continuation is suspended in your Servlet the HTTP socket will be hold. As long as you're not going to perform a long-lasting push to a Web client, timeout should be set to the estimated maximum time of the operation that your Servlet does. Otherwise, you may run out of sockets.